# Is revocation possible in fabric-ca?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am trying to do user authentication mechanism using fabric-ca. So i need to know whether revocation is possible in fabric-ca or not?

Just tried the same with fabric-ca. And now looking into hyperledger indy for identity management. Anyhow wished to know whether it is possible with fabric-ca or not.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more exactly what you want to do and what you have tried?
Fabric CA supports revoking certificates and generating CRLs for distribution.

Comment: Actually our aim is to achieve the user authentication mechanism. Hence tried by using fabric-ca. We registered and enrolled the user, fetched the details of the registered user using sqlite browser. After that when we searched the fabric-ca for user authentication mechanism, obtained some results like user authentication mechanism is not possible using fabric-ca. But while running the commands for installing fabric-ca, a folder called idemix got created in fabric-ca directory. In that, there are some go files including revocation_authority.go, revocation_key.go etc.How could we achieve this?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you actually mean here.  Fabric CA provides crypto material to registered users.  It can issue two type of credentials:  PKI (X509)  credentials or Identity Mixer credentials.   It also provides APIs to revoke either type of credential and provide the CRL for use by consumers of Fabric CA credentials.